# Angular HTTP GET Cors Error while calling get observable

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I'm developing an Angular Project... The Backend is Running Properly.. But I'm unable to get the response in angular.. I've included the json response while using through postman (below)

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdHJVc2VySUQiOiJBRE1JTiIsImlhdCI6MTU1NTk0NzI3MywiZXhwIjoxNTU1OTU4MDczfQ.6NA_8hh6bXQ83UC5EwizKca_uo9VCxTvZR-aS9MMcmE",
"auth":true}
```

But Instead of logging the json response... its showing cors error... I have included the error which I'm getting from the console (below)

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/login/ADMIN/QSKJBCVIHQ/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/login/ADMIN/QSKJBCVIHQ/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://localhost:5000/login/ADMIN/QSKJBCVIHQ/", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/login/ADMIN/QSKJBCVIHQ/: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }
core.js:15724
```

```js
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Form, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { CommonService } from '../CommonService/common.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      LoginForm: Form;
      private router: Router;
      strIP: string;
      loginStatus: boolean;
      loginTokenMessage: any;

      constructor(private ClsCommon: CommonService, private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get<{ ip: string }>('https://jsonip.com')
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log('ip', data);
            this.strIP = data.ip;

          })
      }

      ngOnInit() {

      }
      private loginApiURL: string;

      OnSubmit(UserID: string, UserPwd: string) {
        this.loginApiURL = 'http://localhost:5000/login/' + UserID.toUpperCase() + '/' + UserPwd.toUpperCase() + '/'
        this.http.get<Observable<{ token: string, auth: boolean }>>(this.loginApiURL, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
          .subscribe(response => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
          })
      }

    }
```

I have added the required header in app.js of the express backend

```
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});
```

Comment: What's your question? You **know** it's a CORS error. So do what is necessary on your server to accept CORS requests. Or avoid having to use CORS by serving both your API and your angular application from the same server.

Comment: I’ve have added all headers... but then also I’m getting error....

Comment: @JBNizet please have a look in the error... I’ve included all headers in express.... there might be some problem with angular please review

Comment: If you had added all the necessary headers, you wouldn't have an error, especially an error saying "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing". Angular is not the problem. CORS issues are solved by modifying the **server** code.

Comment: @JBNizet   

**
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
**

Comment: I don't know anything about Express. Edit your question, add the relevant code there, and tag it with the correct tags.